# Where is my php.ini file?

Tags: php, sftp

Getting error on live server

> Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

On my local machine it working fine because i remove comment from line `extension=php_ssh2.dll` in php.ini file. But same file when i uploaded on live server i am getting error

> Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

and i can't find php.ini file on my live server to edit. Just help me how to install or how SSH2 will work on live server.

Comment: Do you have root access to your server? What distribution is it?

Comment: yes i have a root access to server .........

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the php ini by running the following command in a shell

`php -i | grep ini`

The output should give you an idea to where the ini file is located (look for the line *Loaded Configuration File*). Next you'll need to compile the ssh2 module and activate it in php, you can use the PECL extension for that

`pecl install ssh2`

*This ofcourse assumes your server is running a linux/unix OS and pecl and php-cli are available.*

Comment: Very often CLI php.ini is different than the php.ini used through Apache.

Comment: Well, you said that you had root access to your server, but could not open shell ? Then you only have FTP/SFTP access? If yes, really looks like a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know which php.ini is used is to make a PHP file calling phpinfo():

```
<html>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
</html>
```

Then you call it from your browser. You will know what php.ini file was loaded, what extensions are enabled, configuration, etc.

Comment: yes i did this and it shows install extensions and where is my php.ini file is located, in result its not showing SSH2 extensions and the path of php.ini file is usr/bin/..... something like that but i cant find folder usr/bin/.... in my whole cpanel.....

Comment: Is your server a dedicated one ? Looks like you're using a shared one, with access only to your subtree. In this case, php.ini won't be available for modification.